# Como Modifcar Datos almacenados en un Vector C++

Tags: c++

Buenas Noches, pues lo siguiente es que no se como hacer para poder modificar los datos que se van almacenando en un vector. En mi programa pido los datos de trabajadores (Nombre y Cedula). Luego al final lo que quiero es Lograr Modificarlos, a partir de ejemplo pido la cedula, y que me permite cambiar el nombre o cedula de esa persona. El codigo es el siguiente: (la parte que es necesaria). Como se puede realizar dichar logica?

**Aqui Pido los Datos**

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    total_mensual[i] = 0;
    sueldo_mensual[i] = 0;
    seguro[i] = 0;
    bono_mensual[i] = 0;
    sueldo_semana_total[i] = 0;
    cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Nombre del Trabajador: "<<i<<". ";
    cin>>nombre[i];
    cout<<"\nCedula del Trabajador: ";
    cin>>cedula[i];
```

**Aqui como parte de un Menu y una Opcion es donde quiero que me permita Modificar los Datos de un Trabajador a partir de una cedula dada**

```
case 3:

        system("cls");
        cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
        cout<<"\n\nOpcion 3: Modificar Datos de los Trabajadores";
        cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Numero de Cedula: ";
        cin>>modificar;

        for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            if (modificar == cedula[i])
            {
                cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
                cout<<"\n\nNombre del Trabajador: "<<nombre[i];
                cout<<"\n\nCedula: "<<cedula[i];
                cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
            }       
        }

        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya que encontraste el registro que quieres modificar `i` indica dicho registro ya solo haces `cin >> nombre[i];` para cambiar el valor actual por el nuevo

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            if (modificar == cedula[i])
            {
                cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
                cout<<"\n\nNombre del Trabajador: "<<nombre[i];
                cout<<"\n\nCedula: "<<cedula[i];
                cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
                cout<<"\n\ningrese el nuevo nombre:";
                cin >> nombre[i];
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera haciendo otra función que devuelva dicha posición donde está la cédula en el vector:

```
int buscarcedula (int cedulabuscar, int vectorcedula[]) {
    for (i = 0 ; i < vectorcedula.size() ; i++) {
        if (cedulabuscar == vectorcedula[i]) {
         return i;
        }      
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Este es la implementación el el menú:**

```
case 3:
        cout << "Opcion 3: Modificar Datos de los Trabajadores"<< endl;
        cout << "Ingrese el Número de Cédula: " << endl;
        cin >> cedulamodificar;
        pos = buscarcedula(cedulamodificar, vectorcedula); # (pos) almacena la posision que se encontro la cedula en el vector.
        if ( pos == -1) {
         # Por si se da el caso que no se encuentra la cédula ingresada
          cout << "La cédula indicada no fue encontrada."<< endl;
        } else {
          cout << "Indique lo que quiere modificar de la cédula: " <<cedulamodificar<< endl;
          cout << "1./ Cédula" << endl; # Una vez encontrado pregunta que dado modificar.
          cout << "2./ Nombre" << endl
          cin >> opc;
          if (opc == 1) {
              cout << "Indique la nueva cédula" << endl;
              cin >> vectorcedula[pos]
          } else {
              cout << "Indique el nuevo nombre" << endl;
              cin >> vectornombre[pos]
          }
        }
        break;
```

Espero entiendas lo que quise hacer en este fragmento de código, nótese que omití la declaración de las variables que usa el código de ejemplo.